# After the transition to tfs 2017 fall autotests

Tags: tfs, coded-ui-tests, release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

after upgrading to TFS 2017 have ceased to take place autotest issues, before everything worked fine. Can someone faced? On the Deploy TestAgent step drops. Log attached. Tried the new / old / default from the Internet TestAgent, nothing helps.[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHDya.png)
[Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzaTZ7KD63YVYl9GMnRxX3Y3eTg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please change another account in the "Test Agent deploy agent" step,  the account must be an administrator of the "wlab-40" computer. Could you please install the test agent 2015 manually on that machine and could   it be installed successfully?

Comment: zav\autorazv is an administrator on computer wlab-40. Agent 2015 update 3  is successfully installed on the wlab-40.

Comment: I saw a lot of junk characters in your logs, which language do you use?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The error was in the Russian project name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the Russian project name.